# No me deja acceder a la memoria en Visual Studio 2022, me especifica (el error) que la variable 'lista' no esta definida

Tags: c++

tengo un problema a la hora de acceder a la memoria de una variable (en este caso list de tipo char) ya que me refleja el error de 'no está definida', no se que puede ocurrir, cambié el código 4 veces para ver si el error que tenía era que no instanciaba la variable a la hora de crearla, pero no parece ser, si alguien me ayuda estaría muy agradecido.

```
void MultiValueControl_T8() {
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;

    cout << "Escoge el primer valor: ";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Escoge el segundo valor: ";
    cin >> b;

    cout << "Escoge el tercer valor: ";
    cin >> c;

    char lista[3] = {a, b, c };

    

    int resultado = lista[0] ^ lista[1] ^ lista[2];
    if (resultado != 172) {
        cout << "Estos no son los androides que buscais";
        exit(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pues parece que compila sin mayor problema: https://wandbox.org/permlink/eg4bx0SFCcA46ANf

Comment: @Trauma si, compilar si, pero a la hora de tratar de acceder a la memoria me refleja que no se pudo porque la variable no está definida, quiza sea un error del propio visual

Comment: Yo también lo puedo compilar y funciona sin problemas. Puedes mostrar el error exacto que obtienes y que configuración utilizas?. Una variable no definida es un error de compilación...